# Saleforce Test Classes for CPQ API Models

Tags: salesforce, apex

I'm a bit new to creating Salesforce apex. I'm looking to implement Saleforce CPQ API. Do we need to create test classes for the CPQ API Models?
Link: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.cpq_dev_api.meta/cpq_dev_api/cpq_api_models.htm

Sample api model code:

```
public class QuoteModel {
    public SBQQ__Quote__c record;
    public QuoteLineModel[] lineItems;
    public QuoteLineGroupModel[] lineItemGroups;
    public Integer nextKey;
    public Boolean applyAdditionalDiscountLast;
    public Boolean applyPartnerDiscountFirst;
    public Boolean channelDiscountsOffList;
    public Decimal customerTotal;
    public Decimal netTotal;
    public Decimal netNonSegmentTotal;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class shown in this question contains no executable lines of code, only variable declarations. Classes of this kind cannot be tested and have no code coverage requirements. Test classes will become required only when executable code is added to the class.